# How can I make Bootstrap Badge buttons the same width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I force these these Bootstrap badge buttons to have the same width?

The `width:100px` doesn't have any effect:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/gbwgv71e/1/

```
<div style="width:100px" title="new flashcards" class="label label-danger label-as-badge" >0</div> 

<div style="width:100px" title="flashcards you have taken before" class="label label-warning label-as-badge">11</div> 

<div style="width:100px" title="flashcards you have to wait on before you take again" class="label label-default label-as-badge">222</div> 

<div style="width:100px" title="flashcards you've learned" class="label label-success label-as-badge">3333</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Bootstrap sets `.label` elements to *display inline* instead of as a block-level element. Inline elements can't have fixed dimensions as they're fluid. Block-level elements can, but don't sit nicely in a line of text (as you'd expect a label to).

The happy medium is to display labels as an *inline block*, like so:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100px"
     class="label label-danger label-as-badge">0</div>
```

There are [known issues with IE6 and IE7](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for this technique but its becoming decreasingly relevant to users out there.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary w-100">XYZ</span>
```

Comment: Much simpler, much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following style to `span` or `div` tag for fixed width using inline styling —

```
 style="width: 50px"
```